# Some terminologies to clarify

Tags: .net, dependencies

What **delay-load dependencies\functions** are meant for in the following document?

http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to parse your question.  Delay-load is a feature of unmanaged code.  It won't load a DLL until the program actually makes a call to a function exported in the DLL.

DependencyWalker is quite unsuitable for managed code.  Assemblies are dynamically loaded by the JIT compiler, DependencyWalker cannot see such assembly references.